# I would like to show the TotalSales by Single Column but I would like to show another 2 columns in the output

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table like below and I would like to show TotalSales based on Category column.

| Category | Sub-Cate | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Chairs | Paper | 16.448 |
| Suppliers | Binders | 3.54 |
| Chairs | Art | 85 |
| Suppliers | Binders | 45.89 |
| Furniture | Paper | 75.235 |

I'm trying to use this query:
select Category,sales,TotalSales from (
select Category,Sales,
case when Category='Office Supplies' then sum(sales)
when Category='Furniture' then sum(sales)
end as TotalSales
from Orders$
group by  Category,Sales ) as tmp
order by Category desc

I would like to show as below.

| Category | Sub-Cate | Sales | TotalSales | Percentage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chairs | Paper | 16.448 | 101.448 | % |
| Suppliers | Binders | 3.54 | 49.43 | % |
| Chairs | Art | 85 | 101.448 | % |
| Suppliers | Binders | 45.89 | 49.43 | % |
| Furniture | Paper | 75.235 | 75.235 | % |

can anyone help to get this query.

Note: Percentage= Sales/Sub-Cate Total Sales

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you need this, hope it helps :

Let's assume that your table name is *TableName*.

```
Select tn.Category,
       tn.Sub_Cate,
       tn.Sales,
       tn1.TotalSales,
       ((tn.Sales * 100) / tn1.TotalSales) PercOfTotal
  from TableName Tn
  join (Select category,
               sum(Sales) TotalSales
          from TableName Tn1
         group by 1      
               ) tn1 on tn1.category = tn.category
 order by 1,2,3
```

Answer (score 0):

In the immortal [words](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:12864646978683) of Tom Kyte, the Oracle grandmaster who launched "Ask Tom", "analytics rock, analytics roll."

Analytics is another name for window functions. What the windows function gives you is the ability to compute some aggregate function like sum() but make it available to every row in the group.

```
create table sales(category varchar,subcate varchar,sales float);
insert into sales values ('Chairs','Paper',16.448);
insert into sales values ('Chairs','Art',85);
insert into sales values('Suppliers','Binders',3.54);
insert into sales values('Suppliers','Binders',45.89);
insert into sales values('Furniture','Paper',75.235);
```

Now according to your question we need the total sales for each category and use it to create a percentage for each row (different subcate).
The sum() window function works perfectly for that. The "partition by" column or columns if you need more than one, are the columns you would group by in order to get your sum, but doing it this way gives you that sum associated for each row

```
select 
    category,
    subcate,sales,
    sum(sales) over (partition by category) totalSales,
    100*sales/sum(sales) over (partition by category) pct 
from sales;
```

Comment: You are welcome @HarishKumar  If it answer your question in a helpful way it would be good to mark it as accepted answer so that others can find it easily.  If not, comments are always appreciated to help improve the answer.

Comment: Sure, Rob. Will mark as helpful. Once again thank you.